# How do I get transparent text?

Tags: text-manipulation, transparency

I am trying to make a picture for the cover of my thesis using LaTeX. I have a background picture and I would like to have transparent (math) text on top of it, how do I achieve this? I have tried to install the transparent package, but was not successful.

Comment: I am amazed you have the latitude to do this in a thesis! When I wrote mine we had a very tough spec on typesetting.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Here is a non-TikZ solution. We specify the transparency using `\transparent{<value>}`, where the value is from 0 to 1 (0 will make the text invisible and 1 will make the text stay the same as before using the `transparent` package). Adjust the values to suit.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{color}
 \usepackage{transparent}
 \begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{./graphics/amato}\par
\vspace*{-3cm}
\hspace*{-1cm} \hbox{%
 \bfseries\Huge
 \color{red}%
 \transparent{0.4}%
 MY THESIS
 }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for the only non-TikZ answer :-) (Didn't know about the `transparent` package before.)

Comment: it works only with pdftex, not with xelatex, if i am right

Comment: having \usepackage{transparent} in my document seems to break the use of \node[opacity=X,...] for all tikz nodes if I try to use the \transparent inside the text of a node.

Answer (score 33):

You could use a `tikz` node and include the `opacity` option:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=5.0cm]{images/eiffel_tower}};
\node [opacity=0.2] (0,0) {\scalebox{5.0}{\textcolor{green}{$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{x^n}$}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

You may do this with TikZ. In the following solution I put an overlay picture in the title. When the titlepage is printed, it adds the overlay picture. You have to compile this at least twice.

Please note that this solution *does* put the transparent text on the titlepage, as requested, and should work for any document class. You can control the position of the transparent text by providing a proper coordinate in the `\draw` command. In the example it's `current page.center` but it can be anywhere on the page.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\title{How I Got My MSc\overlay@picture}
\author{Me}

\newcommand\overlay@picture{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[fill opacity=0.5]
     (current page.center)
     node[scale=10] {$A = B$};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\mainmatter
\ldots
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please not code-only answers.

Comment: I don't see any problem if the code is fairly simple and self-explanatory, as in this case.

Answer (score 5):

When using OpTeX, we don't need Tikz:

```
\hbox{\rlap{\picw=5cm \inspic{eiffeltower.jpg}}%
   \raise3cm\hbox{\transparency150 \Green
       \typosize[50/]$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty {1\over x^n}$}}
\bye
```

[image: Eiffeltower]