# Make area of image (or PDF) transparent to put text on top

Tags: graphics, pdfpages, transparent

On making a photo book (using the book document class) how to "block out" an area of the image, making only this area transparent/opaque, with the aim of fitting text on top in this area?

There is some documentation on how using *tikz* one can give the text a color background, but this is not the solution. Currently this is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{pdfpages,changepage,lipsum}
\usepackage[papersize={8.5in,8.5in}]{geometry}
\begin{document}
 \begin{figure}[!th]
  \includepdf[height=\paperheight,width=\paperwidth]{example.pdf} % (a square pdf)
 \end{figure}
 \vspace{6cm}
 \begin{adjustwidth}{5cm}{}
  \lipsum[1] % how to make the area of the image behind this text area transparent? 
 \end{adjustwidth}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are not particularly clear in your description of the goal. What exactly is it you want and why is `tikz` not a solution? It can deliver both transparent texts and backgrounds.

Comment: It is possible that *tikz* is a solution, though it isn't clear exactly how to make a part of the *image* transparent (not the text, as is amply discussed elsewhere (e.g. [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40470/how-do-i-get-transparent-text))?

Comment: Why would you want to make the *image* transparent which is *behind* the text? Instead, I would lay a semi-transparent text box over the image.

Comment: Thanks. That seems to be it, c.f. [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199659/text-with-semi-transparent-color-filled-box).